# kubernetes nodes status "NotReady" on autoscaling in aws

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, nodes, autoscaling

Can anybody help me in autoscaling. I am trying to autoscale . Pods used to scale up but when pod scale 
upto 16 then all nodes get status "Not Ready" and after few min most of the pods get status unkown.
I am trying to autoscale in aws. 
I am using kubernetes version 1.10.10
amd kops version 1.10.0

Please help me in this why not get state "not ready"

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because your nodes are not equipped in terms of resources(memory or cpu) to handle more pods and current pods has already consumed most of the resources, hence becomes not ready. To handle this situation, either you can increase the resources on your nodes or you create a cluster which auto scale.

If you can check the resources consumed by pod on each node, it will be very clear. Check the following guide to build large cluster in kubernetes.

https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/cluster-large/

A guide to create auto scalar cluster [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/autoscaler/tree/master/cluster-autoscaler)

Hope this helps.

Comment: actually cluster used to autoscale when I use this "kubectl run php-apache --image=gcr.io/google_containers/hpa-example \
        --requests=cpu=200m --expose --port=80"

Comment: Cluster autoscale means the number of nodes in the cluster increase if your load increases on the nodes

Comment: actually cluster used to autoscale when I use this "kubectl run php-apache --image=gcr.io/google_containers/hpa-example \
        --requests=cpu=200m --expose --port=80"      And autoscale "kubectl autoscale deployment php-apache --cpu-percent=5 --min=2 --max=20" Then cluster used to autoscale. nodes use to autoscale. And status also show ready. But When I autoscale the microservice base then it after 16 pods node status change to "Node Ready"   .

Comment: can anybody help in this?